# QXF File Format Spec

Tags: specifications, quicken

Where can I find a specification or parser/reader library for Quicken Exchange Format (.qxf)?

QXF's predecessor format, [Quicken Interchange Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicken_Interchange_Format) (.qif) is somewhat [documented](http://web.archive.org/web/20100222214101/http://web.intuit.com/support/quicken/docs/d_qif.html). There are various third-party libraries which can be used to read and programmatically manipulate QIF files. However, I can't find anything describing the spec for QXF files and third-party tooling for it appears [almost](https://www.moneythumb.com/convert-to-spreadsheets/) non-existent.

I'm guessing there might not be a published spec (thus the lack of third-party tooling) but I thought I would check here just in case I am mistaken. :-)

**Note:** This question is about qxf files (used to import and export data from Quicken) **not** [Quicken Web Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QFX_%28file_format%29) (.qfx) files (used to load financial institution transactions into Quicken).

Answer (score 0):

Quicken rarely publish specifications for their data interchange formats and the best option is to "reverse engineer" an exported qxf file (which I assume is an XML file) and generate code able to parse the files. Of-course, this is fraught with the danger that an XML file does not define the value properties and may not list all the fields if not populated (i.e non mandatory fields).

If you have a "maximum usage" qxf file and require help in generating code to parse it, then provide one.

Comment: It is not an XML file. A qxf is a binary file that even lacks any recognizable strings inside it, lending some credit to @user3723239's speculation that it's been somehow encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

The QXF file does not appear to be an XML file.  Rather, the file appears to be in an encrypted format.  The file, when opened in Notepad++, shows no human readable data and shows mainly binary coded data.  I am not encryption expert, but the data sure look like they are encrypted.