# Export to Quickbooks

Tags: excel, quickbooks, vba

In Excel VBA, I need to take data in Excel and reformat/rearrange/etc. it for Quickbooks, and export it to a file that Quickbooks can import.

Where can I find information about how the data should be arranged for Quickbooks to be able to import it?

Comment: I did that once.  (Ages ago.)  I think I just created a Quickbooks export and used that to decide what the format was that was being used, so that I could then build a file in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

Quickbooks reads a .qxf file format. I'd suggest you search for qxf file conversion. Or look here for a similar question: [QXF File Format Spec](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30488370/509840)

Quickbooks probably imports other formats that are less opaque, as well.